# jQuery previous button needs to be invisible on first Q.)1 & jQuery Next button needs to be invisible on last page which is Q.)10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

Okay, so I'm running into a slight problem, I have two jQuery buttons "previous" and "Next", now what i need to do is to make previous button invisible on first question because you can not go backwards and next button invisible on the last page because it is the last final page. What is the best way possible to go about this. Here's my code.....

```
     if (i.Question_Type == "DROPDOWN")
    {

        <div class="container text-center">


                <div class="row idrow" data-questions="@counter">
                    @{counter++;
                    }




                        <div id="question1" class="form-group">
                            <label class="lab text-center" for="form-group-select">
                                @i.Question_Order @Html.Raw(@i.Question)
                            </label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="form-group-select">
                                @for (int x = 1; x <= Convert.ToInt32(i.Question_SubType); x++)
                                    {
                                        var t = x - 1;
                                        if (i.qOps != null)
                                        {
                                        <option> @i.qOps.options[t]</option>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        <option> @x</option>

                                        }
                                    }
                            </select>
                        </div>







                </div>

        </div>

                        }

                        if (i.Question_Type == "RADIO")
                        {




        <div class="container">
            <div class="row idrow" data-questions="@counter">
                @{counter++;
                }
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="lab" for="questions">
                       @i.Question_Order @i.Question
                    </label>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div id="question1" class="radio-inline">
                                @for (int x = 1; x <= Convert.ToInt32(i.Question_SubType); x++)
                                {
                                    var t = x - 1;
                                    if (i.qOps != null)
                                    {
                                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="question"> @i.qOps.options[t]</label>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {

                                          <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" min="0" max="@x" name="question"></label>

                                    }
                                }
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

    }
    if (i.Question_Type == "CHECKBOX")
    {
        for (int y = 1; y <= Convert.ToInt32(i.Question_SubType); y++)
        {
            @*<div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <label>@y</label>   <input type="checkbox" name="question">

                </div>
            </div>*@
        }
    }

}
<div class="azibsButtons">
    <button type="button" id="previous"  class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Prev</button>

    <button type="button" id="next"  class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next</button>
</div>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".idrow").each(function (i) {

            var inner = $(this).data('questions');
            if (inner == 0) {

                $(this).removeClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('hidden');

            }
        });
        $("#next").click(function () {

            $(".idrow").each(function (i) {

                var inp = $(this);
                if (!inp.hasClass('hidden')) {
                    var dataVal = inp.data("questions");
                    dataVal++;
                    inp.addClass('hidden');


                    $('[data-questions=' + dataVal + ']').removeClass('hidden');

                    return false;

                }
            });
        });

            $("#previous").click(function () {

                $(".idrow").each(function (i) {

                    var inp = $(this);
                    if (!inp.hasClass('hidden')) {
                        var dataVal = inp.data("questions");
                        dataVal--;
                        inp.addClass('hidden');


                        $('[data-questions=' + dataVal + ']').removeClass('hidden');

                        return false;

                    }

                });
            });


    });

</script>
```

Comment: what you expected from `return false;` to do??

Comment: Do not know much jqurey but i believe it doesn't make a difference

Comment: I think  no need  for `.each()` at all on `next` or even on `previous`  you should just make check if the not hidden element is the first one hide `prev` button and if its the last one hide `next` button .. create a demo with related (html , css , js) code

Comment: the .each() is there because the questions are linked do a data table which also has question order so the .each() loop is garbing the order

Comment: Kindly share the HTML too, so as to better understand the problem and flow.

Comment: Instead of doing `.each` at every step, convert that to a function and call whenever needed.

Comment: just shared the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be something like this .. try this and let me know if you need any explanation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  ShowTheelement(0);                     //run a function 
  $("#previous").addClass('hidden');     // hide the previous button

  var dataVal = 0;                       // set dataVal to 0

  $("#next").click(function () {
    dataVal++;                           // add 1 to data val on each click
    $("#previous").removeClass('hidden');// show the previous button
    dataVal ==  $(".idrow[data-questions]").length - 1 ? $(this).addClass('hidden'): $(this).removeClass('hidden');  // similar to if/else statement .. If dataVal equal the numbers of `idrow` - 1 hide the next button if not show the next button
    ShowTheelement(dataVal);  // run a function to hide divs and show just the one we need with new `dataVal`
  });

    $("#previous").click(function () {
      dataVal--;
      $("#next").removeClass('hidden');
      dataVal ==  0 ? $(this).addClass('hidden'): $(this).removeClass('hidden');
      ShowTheelement(dataVal);
  });
});
// function to hide all `.idrow` elements and show the one with `data-questions='"+dataVal+"'`
function ShowTheelement(dataVal){
    $(".idrow").addClass('hidden');
    $(".idrow[data-questions='"+dataVal+"']").removeClass('hidden');
}
```

**Explanation** :

- While you need to add/remove class onload , next button click and previous button click .no need to repeat your code every time. it'll be better to make a function for this and pass the `dataVal` to this function
- For more explanation please read the comments on the code

Comment: what does the ShowTheelement represent?

Comment: @FaizanHaque this a function to hide all the `.idrow` elements and show just the one with the `data-questions` you need to show .. We will need to do this on document ready and on next click and prev click  so instead of repeat our code we can create a simple function for it

Comment: Okay running into a problem i put your code in and apparently it only shows the next bottom, previous button not showing at all

Comment: @FaizanHaque sorry my bad .. hold on

Comment: your fine. And also Thank you for the help

Comment: @FaizanHaque ok answer updated .. I just realize I don't remove the class hidden from the previous button when next button clicked and vice versa .. I think everything should work now

Comment: awesome and it's working!! just the last question it goes to one extra Next button then gets hidden. but awesome work Thanks

Comment: @FaizanHaque you can use `$(".idrow[data-questions]").length - 1` instead of `$(".idrow[data-questions]").length`

Comment: True! Thanks man

Comment: You're welcome @FaizanHaque .. have a great day :-) .. And don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the green check sign under up/down votes arrow .. Good Luck :-)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'll add an explanation .. Thanks